# deployed website cannot receive http post

Tags: c#, asp.net, fiddler

I built a website using ASP.NET web-api to receive some http post data sent to my static ip address. Everything is fine when I tested it on localhost. But it doesn't work when I deployed the website with my static ip address `164.67.192.249:8888`.

After I deployed it,
I used wireshark to capture the http post packet and find I do get the packet send to my ip address with correct path (/api/recv).

I also used fiddler to generate a http post with same format and sent to `164.67.192.249:8888/api/recv`
and I successfully received the packet and save it to database.

I don't know how to solve this problem. Any suggestion is welcome!

Comment: I Fiddler can send the POST and it is received correctly, then it is most likely a problem with your sending code.  Can you show the code that is trying to send the message?

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by close wireshark. It turns out that wireshark may block the post for some reason.

Comment: Please give some more details. I think that this is not normal for wireshark, as wireshark acts as a sniffer. Perhaps it is a setting of your specific wireshark deployment. Can you reproduce it and check your settings?